# datatables change class of cell with values from other columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jquery datatables and I have the following code:

```
activitiesTable = $('#activitiesTable').DataTable({
      scrollX: true,
      serverSide: true,
      processing: true,
      stateSave: true,
      ajax: {
        url: "...",
        type: "POST",
        data: function ( d ) {
          $.extend(d,ajaxData());
        },
        dataType: "JSON"
      },
      columns: [
        { data: function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
          if (row.jul_from_otl == 1){return row.jul_otl;}else{return row.jul_user;}
          }, 
          createdCell: function (td, row, col) {
              if(row.jul_from_otl == 1){
                $(td).css('color', 'red');
              }
          },
          width: '30px', searchable: false}, 
        { name: 'jul_user', data: 'jul_user', width: '30px', searchable: false , visible: false},
        { name: 'jul_otl', data: 'jul_otl', width: '10px', searchable: false , visible: false},
        { name: 'jul_from_otl', data: 'jul_from_otl', width: '10px', searchable: false , visible: false},
...
```

So you can see that there are 1 column that is the value of the 2nd or the third column depending on the value of the fourth column. If the 4th column is 0, the first column has the value of the 2nd column and if the 4th column is 1 then we use the value of the third column.

It is working fine BUT I would like to change the color of the cell also in case the 4th column is 1. I tried with createdCell but it never works :(.

What I tried also is to use:

```
data: function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
          alert (row.jul_from_otl)
},
```

And then I get a lot of alert with 1 or 0.

But if I do it with createdCell like this:

```
createdCell: function (td, row, col) {
              alert(row.jul_from_otl);
          },
```

I get undefined all the time. So I guess the row values are not passed to createdCell.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(td).css('background-color', 'red');`

Comment: Tried with what you suggest but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I understand now, it is a bit confusing but you need to use row to access the data values in data: ... but you need to use rowData to access the values in createdCell.

So it will look like this in the end:

```
{ data: function ( row, type, val, meta ) {
          if (row.jul_from_otl == 1){return row.jul_otl;}else{return row.jul_user;}
          }, 
          createdCell: function (td, cellData, rowData, row, col) {
              if(rowData.jul_from_otl == 1){
                $(td).css('color', 'green');
              }
          },
          width: '30px', searchable: false},
```